# How do i solve "Expecting NameIDFormat element" issue when configuring Salesforce Marketing Cloud with my Azure ad

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, metadata, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am following Sales Force Marketing cloud documentation [Document link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_single_sign_on_authentication_via_saml_2.htm&type=5)

for enabling SSO with my existing Azure Ad. I have already enabled SSO of my Salesforce CRM with Azure ad with same MetaData way.
However the same metadata for marketing cloud is not working showing **"Expecting NameIDFormat element"** as error

Comment: Hey Prasad, did you get this working at all?

Answer (score 1):

According to the SAML specification the NameID element is optional, however most SAML Service Provider implementation require it for the sake of interoperability.

You may check Salesforce's SP metadata to see which NameID formats are supported.

You need to configure Azure AD so send a value for the NameID being chosen. If 'unspecified' is used, then you must tell Azure AD which value to choose.

If 'transient' is supported by SF, you may better use this.